# Cypress: How to check the modal-checkbox using cypress

Tags: cypress

HTML Code

```
<div class="modal-checkbox" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="label-pp_tool
s_productComparator_8" aria-describedby="description-pp_tools_productComparator_9" aria-checked="false" xpath="1" style="">
</div>
```

Cypress Code:

```
cy.xpath("//div[@data-product-type='visa-platinum-credit card']//div[@role='checkbox']").check().should('be.checked')
```

Cypress Error:
cy.check() can only be called on :checkbox and :radio. Your subject is a:

```
<div class="modal-checkbox" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="label-pp_tools_productComparator_6" aria-describedby="description-pp_tools_productComparator_7" aria-checked="false"></div>
```

Comment: Same for "Combo-box and radio button'.  I am trying to select the checkbox, combo values and also for the radio button in the modal pop-up screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, the `check()` command can only be applied to checkbox elements, but your modal-checkbox is actually made using `<div>` elements.

Instead of `.check()` you can use `.click()`.

```js
cy.xpath(...).click().should('be.checked')
```

Comment: Thanks Amos.Yadlin. Its works. But we also need to use cy.get('div.modal-checkbox').scrollIntoView().should('be.visible').click();